# injector: Store 'x' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, mobx, mobx-react

I have this App.js:

```
render() {
    const hydrate = create({
        storage: AsyncStorage
    });

    hydrate('playerStore', stores.playerStore);
    hydrate('settingStore', stores.settingStore);
    // .then(
    //     // () => console.warn('some hydrated')
    // );

    console.warn("stores: " + JSON.stringify(stores));

    return <Provider {...stores} >
        <AppDrawer />
    </Provider>;
}
```

When I try to inject store from one of my screen (`home`) it's return this error:

```
injector: Store 'x' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider
```

This is my `AppDrawer` code:

```
@inject(["userStore", "listStore"])
@observer
export default class Home extends Component {...
```

And this is my `/store/index.js`:

```
import UserStore from './userStore';
import ListStore from './listStore';

export default {
    userStore: new UserStore(),
    listStore: new ListStore(),
};
```

Can you guide me to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried listing your stores as arguments to `inject` instead of using an array? `@inject("userStore", "listStore")`

Comment: Yes I also tried that.

Comment: are you using `contextTypes` ?

Comment: No can you explain more?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, did you ever figure it out @b24 ?

Comment: @cvDv No, I still have this issue.